# Interact with Flash using Python Mechanize

Tags: python, flash, forms, mechanize, code-injection

I am trying to create an automated program in Python that deals with Flash. Right now I am using Python Mechanize, which is great for filling forms, but when it comes to flash I don't know what to do. Does anyone know how I can interact with flash forms (set and get variables, click buttons, etc.) via Python mechanize or some other python library?

Answer (score 0):

Nice question but seems unfortunately mechanize can't be used for flash objects

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to search for is how to control javascript in a page via python, which can control flash that was specifically designed to accept external javascript calls.

Refers to python-spidermonkey for starters: [mechanize (python) click on a javascript type link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270274/mechanize-python-click-on-a-javascript-type-link)