# Using AutoIT with Selenium

Tags: python, web-scraping

Thank you for answering my previous question but as one is solved another is found apparently.

Interacting with the flash game itself is now the problem. I have tried researching how to do it in Selenium but it can't be done. I've seen FlashSelenium, Sikuli, and AutoIT.

I can only find documentation for FlashSelenium in Java, It's easier for me to use AutoIT rather than Sikuli as I'd have to learn to use Jpython to create the kind of script I want to, which I am not straying away from learning just trying to finish this as fast as possible. As for AutoIT, the only problem with it is that I don't undertsand how to use it with seleium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import autoit
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://na58.evony.com/s.html?loginid=747970653D74727947616D65&adv=index")
driver.maximize_window()
assert "Evony - Free forever " in driver.title
```

So far I have this and It's doing what is suppose to do which is create a new account using that "driver.get" but when I reach to the page, it is all flash and I can not interact with anything in the webpage so I have to use AutoIT but I don't know how to get it to "pick-up" from where selenium left off. I want it to interact with a button on the webpage and from viewing a previous post on stackoverflow I can use a (x,y) to specify the location but unfortunately that post didn't explain beyond that. Any and all information would be great, thanks.

Comment: The missing link: http://imgur.com/Udv1086

Comment: Is your side evony.com developed in Python ? If yes - any framework you used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use any number of scraping libraries ([scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) and [beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) are both easy to use and very powerful). Personally though, I like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) and its [python bindings](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) because they're the most flexible. Your final script would look something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://xx.yy.zz")

# Click the "New comer, click here to play!" button
elem = driver. find_element_by_partial_link_text("Click here to play")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Can you post what the source of the page looks like (maybe using a [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com))?

**Edit:** updated to show you how to click the "Click here to play" button.

Comment: But this doesn't look like HTML, probably a flash game - which means interacting with it will be very difficult.

Comment: @charlesreid1 This is the source for the page displayed in pic 1: http://pastebin.com/S4fQ40Uv

Comment: @charlesreid1 This is the source code for the actual page in the pictures: http://pastebin.com/m8TUHZD7(If you scroll all the way down, the next two links will make sense), This is the one for "s2.html" : http://pastebin.com/2D6JNKbM. The last one for "2.html":http://pastebin.com/9AxAsCQg

Comment: This uses flash (you'll notice in s2.html a bunch of comments about Flash). This might be possible with [python-spidermonkey](https://github.com/davisp/python-spidermonkey/tree/master) as mentioned [in this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215062/interact-with-flash-using-python-mechanize), but I can't help you much beyond Selenium.