# Interact Selenium python with windows

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, automation

I am looking for a class or library used to interact with Windows through selenium python.
I am stuck at a point where I have upload a file to website through python automated script.

Any help greatly appreciated.

[Webpage to be automated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZbjf.png)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import csv
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import win32com.client
#from pyrobot import robot

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
options.add_argument("--no-proxy-server")
options.add_argument("--enable-automation")
options.add_argument("--disable-save-password-bubble")
options.add_experimental_option('prefs',{'credentials_enable_service':False, 'profile':{'password_manager_enabled':False}})


def url(chromepath, urlid, username, password):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromepath, chrome_options=options)
    driver.get(urlid)
    user_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='userid']").send_keys(username)
    user_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='password']").send_keys(password)
    signIn_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='Submit']").click()
    return driver

def element_click(xpath_click):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath_click)))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_click).click()

def element_visible(xpath_visible):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath_visible)))
    driver_visible  = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_visible)
    driver_visible.click()
    return driver_visible

def element_visible_send(xpath_visible, xpath_send, xpath_click):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath_visible)))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_visible).send_keys(xpath_send)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_click).click()

def element_visible_iframe(xpath_visible):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath_visible)))
    driver_visible  = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_visible)
    #driver_visible.click()
    return driver_visible

def switch_frame(xpath_iframe):
    driver.switch_to_default_content()
    #size = len(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe"))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath_iframe)))
    iframe = element_visible_iframe(xpath_iframe)
    driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)

chromepath = 'D:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe'
urlid = "URL"
username = '****'
password = '****'
driver = url(chromepath, urlid, username, password)


user_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='pthnavbca_PORTAL_ROOT_OBJECT']").click()
user_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='fldra_CO_EMPLOYEE_SELF_SERVICE']").click()
sleep(3)
user_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='fldra_HH_FORMS']").click()
sleep(3)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Kimpton CAR Form']")
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
print(window_before)
user_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Kimpton CAR Form']").click()
url = driver.current_url

driver.switch_to_frame('ptifrmtgtframe')
element_click("//abbr[@class='PTUNDERLINE']")
element_visible("//input[@class='PSPUSHBUTTONTBADD']")
element_visible("//input[@value='BUD']")
element_click("//img[@alt='Look up *Business Unit']")
switch_frame('//iframe[contains(@id,"ptModFrame")]')
element_visible_send("//input[@name='HHK_CARBU_DVW_BUSINESS_UNIT']", 'C4053', "//input[@value='Look Up']")
element_visible("//a[@name='RESULT0$0']")
driver.switch_to_default_content()
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it('ptifrmtgtframe'))
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='HH_CAR_FORM_BUSINESS_UNIT'][@value='C4053']")))
element_visible("//img[@alt='Look up *Project']")
switch_frame('//iframe[contains(@id,"ptModFrame")]')
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='PROJECT_PROJECT_ID']")))
driver_visible = element_visible("//input[@value='Look Up']")
print(driver_visible.get_attribute('value'))
driver_visible = element_visible("//a[@name='RESULT1$0']")
project = driver_visible.text
driver.switch_to_default_content()
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it('ptifrmtgtframe'))
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name = 'HH_CAR_FORM_PROJECT_ID'][@value="+project+"]")))

element_visible("//option[@value='B']")
#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='B']").click()
#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='HH_CAR_FRM_DTL_BUDGETED_AMT$1']").send_keys('100000')


AMT = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[contains(@name,"HH_CAR_FRM_DTL_BUDGETED_AMT")]')
print(AMT)
i = 0
for a in AMT:
    a.send_keys('100000')
    a.send_keys(Keys.TAB)  
    x = "HH_CAR_FRM_DTL_HH_BASE_BUDGET_AMT$"+str(i)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[contains(@id,"'+x+'") and contains(text(),".")]')))
    #sleep(3)
    i = i + 1


driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='FFE']").click()
sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='FFE']").click()
```

Comment: Share with us what you have done so far.

Comment: @AlexLucaci i have scripted till that point where the pop up windows comes to attach file from local. Do you want the whole script that I have scripted till now ? You may also need the snapshot of the website I believe. ?

Comment: @AlexLucaci...I am new here. How can I upload snapshot and code for your reference ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: @AlexLucaci...Please check if you can access now. I have edited my question

Comment: @AlexLucaci...I have to click on the add attachment button and afterwards python should interact with windows to select file and upload.

Comment: @Greedy you can use AUTOIT with selenium to interact with window application refer this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30701013/using-autoit-with-selenium