# Log Into Website and Scrape Streaming Data

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I am not really a programmer but am asking this out of general curiosity.  I visited a website recently where I logged in, went to a page, and without leaving, data on that page refreshes before my eyes.

Is it possible to mimic a browser (I was using Chrome) and log into the site, navigate to a page, and "scrape" that data that is coming in using Python?  I would like to store and analyze it.

If so, taking this one step further, is it possible to interact with the website?  Click a button that I know the name of?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, this is all possible using python, if you are a bit more specific we can point you in the right direction, but you might want to look at the python module pyquery for starters as well as urllib. if the data is streaming, it is likely that the website is making ajax requests to refresh the data -- you can make the same requests using python, or most any other language of choice.
once you start scraping you'll see that it is very straightforward.  there are many tutorials that will get you started: http://www.google.com/search?q=scraping+data+with+python

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I wish I could be more specific but I don't really program in Python much (do most of what I need in R).  I am just curious as to how someone with significantly more coding ability that I have would do such a thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data "refreshes before your eyes" it is probably AJAX (javascript in the page pulling new page-data from the server).

There are two ways of approaching this;

1. using Selenium you can wrap an actual browser which will load the page, run the javascript, then you can grab page-bits from the active page.
2. you can look at what the AJAX in the page is doing (how it is asking for updates, what it is getting back) and write python code to emulate that.

both take a fair bit of of time and effort to set up; Selenium is a bit more robust, direct python queries is a bit more efficient, YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

To emulate the browser behavior in Python, you can use the [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) module. The 'streaming' data which you refer to could be flash or javascript. If it is flash, it is going to be binary and you won't be able fetch it. If it javascript, mehanize again seems to [have problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270274/mechanize-python-click-on-a-javascript-type-link) in dealing with that.